# Biopython SeqIO check input file

Tags: fasta, python, seqio

Hi I am trying to learnt python3 and Biopython,

I am trying to check imported fasta file before processing so far using:

```
sequences = SeqIO.parse("fake_fasta_file", "fasta")

if not any(sequa):
        print('\n  SOMETHING IS WRONG WITH YOUR INPUT FILE \n')
        exit()
```

works but as soon as I enter a '>' in my fake_fasta_file , as an example

```
nihvivicòvo-l
,mnjobùJN
, Békibpç
, mnkn

nbigp
ù
mlkn

mlnù
>  ftfyfiuuogpigèi
```

any(sequences) returns True even if:

```
for seq_record in sequences:
       print(seq_record)
```

doesnt print anything

Any better way to check for real fasta file in Biopython ?

Or maybe it my fault using any() on the iterator instead of creating

a list of seq_record and checking on that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`any()` loops over the iterator until the first truthy item is found or the end is reached. The iterator is not reset to the start after this. Using a list will change that behaviour since a list is not exhausted like a iterator. So, remove your `any()` call and you will see a sequence record printed. Your `'fake_fasta_file.fa'` is actually recognised by Biopython as valid fasta:

```
>>> SeqIO.read('fake_fasta_file.fa', 'fasta')
SeqRecord(seq=Seq(''), id='ftfyfiuuogpigèi', name='ftfyfiuuogpigèi', description='  ftfyfiuuogpigèi', dbxrefs=[])
```

Biopython ignores lines before the first line beginning with `'>'` (as possible comment lines) and then starts collecting records, in this case an empty sequence record is still a record. This behaviour is deliberate from Biopython, although you could argue if it's best or not, it's unlikely to change for historical reasons.

What is *real* fasta? (philosophical pause) If you want to validate a particular definition of FASTA format then you can write your own parser depending on the exact specification and rules you want.

Edit, e.g.

```
from Bio import SeqIO

records = SeqIO.parse("myfile.fa", "fasta")
first = next(records, None)
if first is None:
    print("No fasta records")
elif first.seq == "":
    print("Empty sequence")
elif all(c not in "ATCGN" for c in first.seq.upper()):
    print("Non ATCGN characters")
```

etc.

Comment: thank You very much indeed for the very informative and detailed answer. Given I am really a newbie is there any chance you could point me to pre-made fasta validator I could borrow for my script ? (i was thinking about valid if >header than sequence on one or multiple lines and a way to check the characters used in the sequences)

Comment: @pippo1980 see edit (untested)

Comment: cheers !!!!!!!!!